# Join on the basis of RowId

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1=

3    4.760291
1    4.551454
2    4.507637


df2=
1  VeryGood
2  Good
3  NotBad
```

Right now I would like to  Join the Two Dataframe on the basis of RowID,Is it Possible to join two different  dataframes on the basis of RowID(as i don't have any matching column)

```
Expected Output
3    4.760291  NotBad
1    4.551454  VeryGood
2    4.507637  Good
```

Please let me know your thoughts on this in SQL we can do a join on the basis of rowid,please guide me in achieving the above logic

Comment: What is rowId, do you mean index? ie. `df1.join(df2)`?

Comment: Thanks @EdChum. Yes it is based on index.
df2.index[0]=1
df2.index[1]=2
df2.index[2]=3

Comment: So did you try `df1.join(df2)`?

Comment: Thanks a lot @EdChum. It is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC either `join` or `merge` should work here:

```
In [6]:
df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)

Out[6]:
        1_x       1_y
0                    
1  4.551454  VeryGood
2  4.507637      Good
3  4.760291    NotBad
```

I expect `df1.join(df2)` to also work